# How to use menuDisabled inside a tree grid panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

So I have a tree panel which contains some columns like a grid .These columns have menu's enabled by default . I want to completely disable/hide it.I suppose menuDisabled only works in Ext.grid.panel but not in Ext.tree.panel .

here is the fiddle :https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29fr

Can anyone please help and disable 'Assigned To' column's menu from the mentioned fiddle

Comment: Setting menuDisabled config to true in 'Assigned To' column.. disables the column menu and works fine as expected! check the updated fiddle!

Comment: Oh man How can I be this dumb .Did you change anything else ?

Comment: I didn't change anything. I have set the menuDisabled config as true to 'Assigned To' column. Nothing else!